# Bluetooth headphones - click button to mute microphone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, headphones

I've got Ubuntu 20 and I want to buy wireless bluetooth headphones with 3 buttons - for volume up, down, and for pick up a call. Can I use the third button to mute/unmute microphone instead? I can set keyboard shortcut in settings to mute microphone, but is it possible to listen for clicking this button on headphones and pressing this keyboard shortcut then (or just replace this keyboard shortcut by headphones button)?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.